# ipad app crashes on new iOS 4.1.2 but works on 3.2

Tags: ipad, ios4, memory-leaks

I have a app in which i play a splash video and have added some custom fonts.

The app works fine on ipad 3.2 but on 4.2 etc it crashes. The log says that i release something that i dint alloc. I have checked my code a hundred times and i dont do any such thing.

Either ways it works on the simulator and on the device(both 3.2)

any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<Error>: df(7903,0x3e3d7898) malloc: *** error for object 0x1a11b0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Wed Jan 19 20:35:38 unknown UIKitApplication:com..imagazine[0x9c7c][7903]                         <Notice>: def(7903,0x3e3d7898) malloc: *** error for object 0x1a11b0: pointer being           freed was not allocated
 Wed Jan 19 20:35:38 unknown UIKitApplication:com.imagazine[0x9c7c][7903] <Notice>: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
   Wed Jan 19 20:35:39 unknown ReportCrash[7905] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process df[7903]
  Wed Jan 19 20:35:39 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.imagazine[0x9c7c]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap
  Wed Jan 19 20:35:39 unknown SpringBoard[27] <Warning>: Application 'df' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap
  Wed Jan 19 20:35:39 unknown ReportCrash[7905] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/df_2011-01-19-203538_Sumas-iPad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

SOLUTION:

First of all use the NSZombies and you will catch such errors.

The Problem: I had a timer setup for every 0.2sec and it was clearing a UIView and allocating it, not every 0.2secs but maybe once every 5secs. 
I did a standard check:

```
  if(vewCustom!= nil) {
      [vewCustom removeFromSuperView];
      [vewCustom release];
      vewCustom = nil;
   }
```

But the strange thing was i verified the code hundreds of times and I was not over releasing and either ways it worked on iOS4.2 for iPhone.

I removed the Timer but still it was crashing and then I removed the release and now it works fine.

Strange but it would be good if someone can explain what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Show us the backtrace from your crash report on the thread that crashed. Also the exception type shown in the report.

Comment: It "working" doesn't matter.  Wrong code could work sometimes.  How did you create vewCustom?  Did you hold a reference outside of the one that the superview has?  Is vewCustom is a property with retain?

Comment: yes it had a retain property and yes it had a reference outside the superview. But i checked if was nil and then only released it.

Comment: Checking for nil doesn't help.  You could look at the retainCount, but that doesn't tell you if an autorelease is pending.  I think Build and Analyze will give you a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running the app in debug with zombies enabled. This way you'll get a stack trace on the overreleased object here's a link on how to set it up.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled.html

Comment: thanks i was able to spot the error. But its crazy cos i was not calling a release twice.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the log is true.  The easiest way to find it is to enable Zombies and then exercise your application throughly.  See here (tip #1):

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/debugging-memory-iphone.html

Another thing to do is a Build and Analyze and look at each thing it flags.  In my experience there are very few false positives.

Comment: thanks i was able to spot the error. But its crazy cos i was not calling a release twice.

Comment: Did you release something that you weren't supposed to because it was returned after an autorelease is done?

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed this while looking for something else.  The reason for the crash is that removeFromSuperview causes the superview to release the view.  Thus, the release that follows is redundant (over-release).  Won't be an issue with ARC, but could cause some confusion in other situations

Comment: Not really Scott, the removeFromSuperview will decrease the retain count by 1, but unless i call a release or an autorelease on the subview, this will be a memory leak.